# Any way to avoid Install Failed Permission level downgrade on Android?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm getting an error - INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_LEVEL_DOWNGRADE while installing app from adb after targeting sdk 22, coming down from 23.

I have to do this, temporarily because of some other issues but it would not be the best experience for the users updating the app on Google play if they just couldn't. The only solution I know as of now is to uninstall the current version (targeting SDK 23) and then install the update (targeting SDK 22).

Even though there are only a handful of people on Marshmallow right now, it would be best if they don't face this issue.

Does anyone know anything about this?

**Update**: AFAIK nothing can be done in the app or on the console to avoid users uninstalling and installing the app. Luckily, I did it when the users on Marshmallow were few.

Comment: Did you tried incrementing version number?

Comment: @haseeb Yes, tried that. Same error.

Comment: There is a `INSTALL_ALLOW_DOWNGRADE` flag, but I don't know where and how to use that. Try it

Comment: That's maybe for adb or for package managers, I want google play to ignore this if this happens to users while updating the app.

Comment: Hey! Have you got solutions?

Comment: @HardikJoshi best to target the latest sdk. At that moment, we couldn't because of some constraints so we quickly took down the update and had to tell a few users who updated to uninstall the app and then install, but it was not ideal. My advice would be to target the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer does not directly address the question, but may it helps others to achieve a faster solution.

I have created some versions with the following configuration (inside build.gradle) and made them available to alpha- and beta-tester via [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish):

```
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 23
```

When I noticed that users with a deeper system-version could not install the app, I changed the configuration as follows:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 19
```

However, this resulted in the downgrade error message in Google Play Console. So I adapted the configuration that the new version for both
user with a lower system version as well as for users who have installed the current app (with a higher system version).

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 23
```